PHP compare multiple columns in multidimensional array based on conditions
I want to compare multiple columns in a multidimensional array. For example, I have the following array where I need to check if two items have the same type, currency and cost columns and get the one with the oldest date. That's why I have added a column named "compare" where I concatenate all three columns in order to compare them and find duplicate items. But how can I get the item with the oldest date from the duplicate items?
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [objectid] => 38671
            [repgroupitem_id] => 165775
            [type] => Purchase value
            [date] => 2016-12-06
            [cost] => 52254
            [currency] => EUR
            [notes] => just a note
            [refield] => 
            [compare] => 52254-EUR-Purchase value
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [objectid] => 38671
            [repgroupitem_id] => 165776
            [type] => Insurance value
            [date] => 
            [value] => 65000
            [currency] => EUR
            [notes] => 
            [refield] => 
            [compare] => 65000-EUR-Insurance value
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [objectid] => 38671
            [repgroupitem_id] => 170747
            [type] => Insurance value
            [date] => 2021-11-10
            [value] => 65000
            [currency] => EUR
            [notes] => 
            [refield] => 
            [compare] => 65000-EUR-Insurance value
        )

)

And this is my code so far:
$arrCompare  = array_column($arrValues, 'compare'); // get column 'compare' as array 
$tempArr = array_unique($arrCompare);

if(sizeof($arrCompare) != sizeof($tempArr)) { //DUPLICATES FOUND
                                
array_multisort($arrCompare, SORT_ASC, $arrValues); //sort array so that duplicates are together
                                
//STUCK HERE ON HOW TO GET ITEM WITH OLDEST DATE FROM DUPLICATE ITEMS                               
                                    
}   


You can order the array by the date column and pick the first or eliminate all but the first entry for each date.

Filter php array and keep only oldest data on duplicate data

Also topically related: Remove duplicate objects from array based on one value, keep lowest of other value in PHP?
